# Android C#: sending SMS from Android service

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, sms

I have android service written using Xamarin Studio and I'm trying to send sms message from this service automatically. For sending I use the following code:

```
SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage("+7926736XXXX", null, "Simple Service sent you a message", null, null);
```

As a result SMS didn't sent to other mobile but left in SMS list marked by red triangle. I can send them later by hands without any problem. Can anybody know where may be my error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
PendingIntent sentPI;
String SENT = "SMS_SENT";

sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,new Intent(SENT), 0);

sms.sendTextMessage("+7926736XXXX", null, message, sentPI, null);
```

OR 
send it in intent like this

```
var smsUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("smsto:7926736XXXX");
var smsIntent = new Intent (Intent.ActionSendto, smsUri);
smsIntent.PutExtra ("sms_body", "Hello from Xamarin.Android");  
StartActivity (smsIntent);
```

hope this will help.

Comment: The second variant not good because I need to send SMS automatically

Comment: With the fist variant I have the same situation: I see my sms in list of system sms application marked by red triangle

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the `SmsResultError` and `SmsStatus` of the sent and delivered intents to determine why your SMS is not working.

#### Add `BroadcastReceiver` inner class to your `Service`:

```
public YourSMSService : Service
{
    const string SentAction = "SentAction";
    const string DeliveredAction = "DeliveredAction";
    SmsReceiver smsReceiver;

    ~~~~

    class SmsReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.Action == SentAction)
            {
                // `Log` it if needed...
                Toast.MakeText(context, $"{(SmsResultError)ResultCode}", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            if (intent.Action == DeliveredAction)
            {
                // `Log` it if needed...
                Toast.MakeText(context, $"{(SmsStatus)ResultCode}", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
    }

    ~~~~
}
```

#### Create/Register the `BroadcastReceiver` (usually done in the `Service` .actor)

```
smsReceiver = new SmsReceiver();
RegisterReceiver(smsReceiver, new IntentFilter(SentAction));
RegisterReceiver(smsReceiver, new IntentFilter(DeliveredAction));
```

#### Supply sent and delivered `PendingIntent`s to the `SendTextMessage`:

```
var sentIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SentAction), 0);
var deliveredIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DeliveredAction), 0);
SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage("1234567890", null, "Simple Service sent you a message", sentIntent, deliveredIntent);
```

Now when you send an SMS in your service, you will get a `Toast` message of the status.

Comment: I did it already. Just uadn't time to write here. During sending of the SMS message I receive error SmsResultError.RadioOff. As far as I understand (sorry, today is my second day as Android and C# developer :) ) it means that my phone is in "In Airplane" mode, but it isn't true.

Comment: @Hermann Well, if you are getting an `SmsResultError.RadioOff` (`RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF`) that is your root problem... Have a valid SIM? Do you have multiple SIMs in that phone?

Comment: no sim is valid. If I use for sending not SmsManager but Intent all is OK, but I need automatic sending. The phone has one SIM, but it locked by operator, Can it be a reason of my problem?

Comment: @Hermann "`no sim is valid`"? Confused, you are sending SMSs manually and they are being received without a valid SIM/account on the phone?

Comment: Yes, when I send sms from my application by hand all is working. Oh, sorry! "No, sim is valid" :) I forgot comma :)

Comment: @Hermann Try another phone to see if you get `SmsResultError.RadioOff` on that one also ..... As long as you are getting that error, the messages will not be sent and show as errored in your SMS outgoing listing.... Maybe the default `SMSC` on that phone is incorrect...

Comment: I did it already. All is working with my old chinese phone :) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

The question is closed. This is the hardware problem of the my phone. I connected my 10 yeas old chinese Samsung Galaxy copy and my application immediately started to work